# Does the abelianisation functor $\mathrm{Grp} → \mathrm{AbGrp}$ preserve composition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-groups, functors

I am to show there is a functor $F : \mathrm{Grp} → \mathrm{AbGrp}$. I have already checked that the assignments $F_0(G) := G_{\mathrm{ab}} := G/[G,G]$ and $F_1  (f \colon G → H) := \bar{f}: G_{\mathrm{ab}} → H_{\mathrm{ab}}$ are well-defined. (Using some elementary algebra theorems about factoring through quotients.)

In checking that $F$ preserves composition, however, I run into some trouble. I have seen that for $f \colon G → H$ and $g \colon H → K$ group homomorphisms, $F_1(g ∘ f) = \overline{g ∘ f}$ and $F_1(f) ∘ F_1(g) = \bar{f} ∘ \bar{g}$ are both maps $G_{\mathrm{ab}} → K_{\mathrm{ab}}$. (All this required some verification using factorisation through quotient groups to the abelianised groups.)

However, I fail to see that these maps are *the same*! I could of course evaluate them on the elements of $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$, but I’m learning category theory and therefore want to show this not the ‘intrinsic’ way but the ‘extrinsic’ way. Now I drew the following diagrams, to show my thinking:

[image: I drew the following diagrams]

such that both $\bar{f}, \bar{g}$, and $\overline{g ∘ f}$ appear.

Now what I know is that, for instance $g ∘ f = \overline{g ∘ f} ∘ \pi_G$.

What I’d *like* to do is just chase the diagrams to show $\overline{g ∘ f} = \bar{g} ∘ \bar{f}$ holds.

What would help is if $\pi_H$ would be the identity¹, which would be so if $H$ were already abelian. Because then, we would just conclude that
$$\overline{g ∘ f} ∘ \pi_G = \bar{g} ∘ \bar{f} ∘ \pi_G \,.
$$
Which would bring us a lot closer. (Still not sure how to finish then, though.)

¹In a sense, this should indeed be true, because $\bar{f}$, I think, should automatically map to an abelian group (one of the aforementioned elementary algebra theorems). HOWEVER, and this is where I get really confused, *at no point was* $H$ *itself* to be required anything but a general group!

I feel like I’m really close here, so could someone help me fill in the gaps / patch up the mistakes in my thinking?

Best wishes!

Comment: Your digrams are incorrect! If $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $\overline{f}$ is the unique arrow $G_{ab}\to H_{ab}$ such that $\overline {f}\circ \pi_G= \pi_H\circ f$. Maybe you find the solutions after you fixed your diagrams :)

Comment: Ahhh, so not onlynwere my diagrams incorrect, the assignment $F_1$ wasn’t even well-defined! This seems to indeed precisely fix the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Nico, I may have spotted one mistake: are you sure that $\bar{f}$  maps to $H_{\text{ab}}$? Don’t you mean $f_ {\text{ab}}$? (Which I am yet to construct.. Is there just an existence proof for that or an explicit expression?) See edit to my post.

Comment: Ahh, I thought you were writing $f\mapsto \overline{f}$ for the action of the functor on morphisms. If not, then the equation you are trzing to show is the wrong one, You need to show that $(f\circ g)_{ab} = f_{ab} \circ g_ {ab}$

Comment: Yess. And then my next question was: what is $f_\text{ab}$ exactly? Can we give an explicit expression, or just an existence proof? (Preferably, I’d like to see how $f_\text{ab}$ arises in categorical terms.. But maybe I should just revisit some elementary algebra)

Comment: see my first comment but replace $\overline f$ by $f_{ab}$. that is its definition! it is defined through the mapping out property of tha abelianization. if you so like $f_{ab} = \overline{\pi_H\circ f}$. Hope it helps :)

Comment: In case you didn't know yet and might be interested in this fact: The abelianisation functor $\mathbf{Grp}\rightarrow\mathbf{AbGrp}$ is the left adjoint to the canonical inclusion $\mathbf{AbGrp}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{Grp}$, which makes $\mathbf{AbGrp}$ a reflective subcategory of $\mathbf{Grp}$. See here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory

Comment: The fact that a group homomorphism $\phi\colon G\rightarrow H$ with $H$ abelian factors over a unique group homomorphism $\widetilde\phi\colon G_\mathrm{ab}\rightarrow H$ corresponds to the fact, that using $\mathbf{AbGrp}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{Grp}$ is full as well as this adjunction, we have:
$\phi\in\mathbf{Grp}(G,H)\cong\mathbf{AbGrp}(G_\mathrm{ab},H)=\mathbf{Grp}(G_\mathrm{ab},H)\ni\widetilde\phi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your diagrams are wrong: you claim that $\overline{f}$ is a morphism from $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$ to $H_{\mathrm{ab}}$, but in the diagram it is drawn from $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$ to $H$.
Similarly for $\overline{g}$.

However, if we draw the arrows correctly, then your approach works:

The universal property of the abelianization tells us that for every group $G$, every abelian group $A$ and every homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $A$, there exists a unique morphism $\overline{f}$ from $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$ to $A$ with $\overline{f} ∘ π_G = f$.

It follows that for every homomorphism $f \colon G \to H$, there exists a unique homomorphism $f_{\mathrm{ab}} \colon G_{\mathrm{ab}} \to H_{\mathrm{ab}}$ that it makes the following diagram commute:
$$
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  G_{\mathrm{ab}}  @>{f_{\mathrm{ab}}}>>  H_{\mathrm{ab}} \\
  @A{π_G}AA                               @AA{π_H}A       \\
  G                @>>{f}>                H
 \end{CD}
$$
More explicitly, we apply the universal property to the composite $π_H ∘ f \colon G \to H_{\mathrm{ab}}$, so that
$$
 f_{\mathrm{ab}} = \overline{π_H ∘ f} \,.
$$
Note that this does not tell us what $f_{\mathrm{ab}}$ does on elements;
instead, we have constructed $f_{\mathrm{ab}}$ purely in terms of commutative diagrams.

We can now check the functoriality of this construction.

For every group $G$, the following diagram commutes:
$$
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  G_{\mathrm{ab}}  @>{\mathrm{id}_{G_\mathrm{ab}}}>>  G_{\mathrm{ab}} \\
  @A{π_G}AA                                           @AA{π_G}A       \\
  G                @>>{\mathrm{id}_G}>                G
 \end{CD}
$$
The commutativity of this diagram tells us that $\mathrm{id}_{G_\mathrm{ab}}$ satisfies the defining property of $(\mathrm{id}_G)_{\mathrm{ab}}$.
Therefore, $(\mathrm{id}_G)_{\mathrm{ab}} = \mathrm{id}_{G_{\mathrm{ab}}}$.

Suppose now that $f \colon G \to H$ and $g \colon H \to K$ are two composable homomorphisms.
We than have the following commutative diagram:
$$
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  G_{\mathrm{ab}}  @>{f_{\mathrm{ab}}}>>  H_{\mathrm{ab}}  @>{g_{\mathrm{ab}}}>>  K_{\mathrm{ab}} \\
  @A{π_G}AA                               @AA{π_H}A                               @AA{π_K}A       \\
  G                @>>{f}>                H                @>>{g}>                K
 \end{CD}
$$
By leaving out the middle column of this diagram we arrive at the following commutative diagram:
$$
 \require{AMScd}
 \begin{CD}
  G_{\mathrm{ab}}  @>{g_{\mathrm{ab}} ∘ f_{\mathrm{ab}}}>>  K_{\mathrm{ab}} \\
  @A{π_G}AA                                                 @AA{π_K}A       \\
  G                @>>{g ∘ f}>                              K
 \end{CD}
$$
The commutativity of this diagram tells us that the composite $g_{\mathrm{ab}} ∘ f_{\mathrm{ab}}$ satisfies the defining property of the homomorphsim $(g ∘ f)_{\mathrm{ab}}$.
Therefore, $(g ∘ f)_{\mathrm{ab}} = g_{\mathrm{ab}} ∘ f_{\mathrm{ab}}$.

Comment: It very much does! Thanks so much much both to you and to Nico! I learned a lot!

Comment: Alternatively, for identity-preservation, could we now, knowing the expression $(\text{id}_G)_{\text{ab}} = \overline{π_G ∘ \text{id}_G} = \overline{\pi_G}$, not show that $(\text{id}_G)_{\text{ab}}$ is the neutral element on Mor(AbGrp)?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman I assume that $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathrm{AbGrp})$ denotes the set of morphisms in $\mathrm{AbGrp}$. But then I don’t understand what you mean by “the neutral element of $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathrm{AbGrp})$”.

Comment: Well, that for every composable morphism of Abelian groups $f : G → H$ with $(\text{id}_G)_\text{ab}$, $f ∘ (\text{id}_G)_\text{ab} = f$ and the other way around.

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to use the seemingly useful and efficient fact that $\overline{π_G

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to use the seemingly useful and efficient fact that $\overline{π_G ∘ \text{id}_G} = \overline{π_G}$, i.e., using that id$_G$ is already an identity, but then in Grp. For AbGrps $G, H, f : G → H$ now, could we say, as in AbGrp, cleary $π_G = \text{id}_G$, that $f = f ∘ π_G = f ∘ \bar{π_G} ∘ π_G =  f ∘ \bar{π_G}$, so that  $\bar{π_G}$ is indeed a right-identity to $f$? It just doesn't sit right with me that we are now mixing identities of different categories together, and I'm not sure that's allowed...

Comment: In fact, I am now convinced this approach *cannot* even work, as I want to prove that the Grp-morphism $\overline{π}_G$ *equals* the *AbGrp*-morphism $(\text{id}_G)_{\text{ab}}$, which could never be true since there are not morphisms in the same category. It would at least require some embedding functor AbGrp → Grp or sth, but that will only complicate things more, so I will stay with your beautiful explanation. (It's always nice to try out this for yourself, of course, but with an imminent exam, it's not always worth it ;))

Answer (score 3):

Remark that you don't need diagrams. A one-line proof suffices: $\overline{f}$ is defined by $\overline{f} \circ \pi = \pi \circ f$. Now, $\overline{g} \circ \overline{f} \circ \pi = \overline{g} \circ \pi \circ f = \pi \circ g \circ f$ shows that $\overline{g} \circ \overline{f}$ satisfies  the definition of $\overline{g \circ f}$.

Comment: Haha LOL this was actually precisely the proof I was attempting. Nonetheless, it required the construction of $f_{\text{ab}}$. (I misused the bar-notation. In my mind, $\bar{f}$ is the map that suffices $f = \bar{f} ∘ π$. (Btw, your π's aren't the same, right?) In the context of my post, you obviously interpreted as $f_{\text{ab}}$, because my assignment wasn't well-defined after all. All that said, this way I learned much more about the categorical way of thinking, so it's a big win!

Comment: $\pi$ is the *respective* projection. In the same way that we also denote every addition by $+$ even though every additive group has a different one.

Comment: I used $\overline{f}$ since this notation is used in the first paragraph in your question.

Comment: Yes, of course, that was my bad

Answer (score 0):

As I can't quite let it go yet, I will attempt to prove another way that, for an abelian group $G$, $\overline{\pi}_G = \overline{\pi_G ∘ \text{id}_G} =: (\text{id}_G)_{\text{ab}}$ equals $\text{id}_{G_{\text{ab}}}$, by showing that for every composable AbGrp-morphisms $f : G → A$ and $g : A → G$, we have the identities

$\overline{\pi}_A ∘ f = f$ and $f ∘ \overline{\pi}_G = f$.

Of course, the awkward thing here is that here, $\overline{\pi}_G$ is the unique *group* homomorphism s.t. [....]. So if we can 'ignore' the fact that a homomorphism of abelian groups in in particular a homomorphism of groups, we can still use the universal property of $\overline{\pi}_G$ that says that $\overline{\pi}_G ∘ \pi_G = \pi_G$. (And of course the reverse holds as well.) This of course looks meager, because we don't want composition with $\overline{\pi}_G $ to be neutral *just* w.r.t. $\pi_G$ itself, but with all aforementioned $f$'s.

The trick is, I think, that the would have to require that $A = G$, and we are looking at the (unique) identity of Hom$_{\text{AbGrp}}(G, G)$, which is $\text{id}_{G_{\text{ab}}}$.

Then without using the commutative diagram produced by Jendrik, can we indeed prove that $\overline{\pi}_G $ must be  $\text{id}_{G_{\text{ab}}}$?

EDIT

I think we can. On the one hand, we have seen that $(\text{id}_G)_\text{ab} = \overline{\pi_G}$ is the unique map that satisfies $\pi_G ∘ \text{id}_G = \overline{\pi_G} ∘ \pi_G$. But of course, this reduces to
$$\pi_G = \overline{\pi_G} ∘ \pi_G = (\text{id}_G)_\text{ab} ∘ \pi_G
$$

On the other hand, more trivially (and actually using neutrality under composition of identity morphisms), as $\pi_G$ maps to $G_\text{ab}$, we can write the obvious equality

$$\pi_G = \text{id}_{G_{\text{ab}}} ∘ \pi_G.
$$

By uniqueness, then, we must conclude that

$$ \overline{\pi_G} = (\text{id}_G)_\text{ab} =  \text{id}_{G_{\text{ab}}}.
$$

(Probably, I have unknowingly drawn some diagonal in Jendrik's commutative square, but it's nice to use the identity $\text{id}_G$ in the process, and it gives yet another perspective. It also gives the insight that the equality that I earlier deemed 'meager', turned out not to be meager at all. (A similar vibe occurs in the Yoneda Lemma, I'm told, but I'm not quite there yet ;).))